# Javascript — Find And Cut if StartsWith

Tags: javascript, startswith

I need to see if the first line of text starts with a `By` and if true, cut the whole line and store it in a variable and remove all blank lines until the next paragraph starts. The method to find `By` needs to be case insensitive and it may have some preceding white spaces too. And `do nothing` if the first line isn't starting with a `By`.

```
var findBy = 'By Bob';
if (findBy.startsWith('By ')) {
findBy = copyBy;
findBy.split("\n").slice(1).join("\n");
}
var pasteBy = copyBy;
```

Let me rephrase myself: Find if first line starts with `By` If it does, save the entire line containing `By` in a variable then delete it.

Comment: _'Thanks :)'_ - you're welcome. BTW, what was your question?

Comment: what you have tried so far??

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your attempts of resolving this issue. **`Tip:`** No source code = nothing to work with.

Comment: HoboSapiens, that's quite witty :) @NewToJS I didn't include what I was trying because JS isn't my playground and I thought let's not make it laughable, But I guess I need to do so. I have updated my question with what I was trying, knowing it won't make any coding sense, but I wish you know that I did try something :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Adjustment** ...

```
function removeBy(textArray) {
  var capture = false;
  rebuild = [];
  for (var i=0,len=textArray.length; i<len; i++) {
    var s = textArray[i].trim();
    if (s.substring(0,3).toUpperCase()==="BY ") {
      capture = true;
    } else if (capture && s!=="") {
      capture = false;
    }

    if (capture) {
      rebuild.push(s);
    }
  }
  return rebuild;
}
```

This function assumes you are sending an array of strings and returns a stripped array.

```
var answer = removeBy(["By Bob", "", "", "This is the result"]);
// answer = ["By Bob"];
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/ojL72L8b/

If the incoming data is separated by line-breaks, you can use the `.strip()` function to make the `textArray`; In reverse, the `rebuild` returned can be put back together with `answer.join("\n");`

**UPDATE**

Based on comments, changed `substring` to `(0,3)` and compared against `"BY "` (space) to ONLY watch for BY not something like BYA.

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/b5gvk48c/1/

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing what I am looking for. It always returns 'answer', whether it starts with a 'By' or not. Please see my updated question again as I might haven't stated the question eloquently.

Comment: Adjusted ... didn't know we were looking for EXACTLY "BY"

Comment: That's OK; I'm just glad I could assist.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your requirements, you could use this regex.
*(maybe not the most powerful, I'm not a regex specialist at all)*

```
/^(\s\bby\b|\bby\b).*$/gmi
```

- Little walkthrough starting by last modifiers :
   `g` *global*, it won't return at first occurence.
   `m` *multiline*, `^` and `$` will match start/end of line, instead of string
   `i` *insensitive*, I bet you got it
- Now, back to the beginning.
   `^` will search at start of the string
   `(x|y)` is a capturing group with two alternatives (x or y)
   `\s\` is any white-space (\r\n\t\f)
   `\bword\b` is a word *boundary*, e.g it won't catch "word**s**"
   `.*` matches any character (except newline), until
   `$` end of string/line here

```js
//those should be found
var text = "by test 1 \n" +
  " by test 2 \n" +
  "By test 3 \n" +
  " By test 4 \n" +

  //Those should not
  "test By 5 \n" +
  "test by 6 \n" +
  "Bya test 7 \n" +
  "bya test 8 \n" +
  " Bya test 9 \n" +
  " bya test 10 \n";

var matchingLines = text.match(/^(\s\bby\b|\bby\b).*$/gmi);

document.querySelector('p').textContent = "|" + matchingLines.join("|") + "|";
```

```html
<p/>
```

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, it also works pretty fine. Thanks for the help :)